# PowerShell Desktop Variable

Tags: powershell, desktop

I am trying to write a PowerShell script to remove the desktop icon for Chrome after installing through sccm. However, certain users in the network have their desktop directed to different folders on the network. **Is there a variable in PowerShell that stores the location of the desktop?**

I have looked online and searched using `Get-Variable | Out-String`, but I didn't find anything. The finished code should look like:

```
If (Test-Path "$DesktopLocation\Google Chrome.lnk"){
    Remove-Item "$DesltopLocation\Google Chrome.lnk"
}
```

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You can use the [`Environment.GetFolderPath()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath) to get the full path to special folders:

```
$DesktopPath = [System.Environment]::GetFolderPath([System.Environment+SpecialFolder]::Desktop)
```

This can be shortened to:

```
$DesktopPath = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")
```

---

You can also get the "AllUsers" shared desktop folder (if the shortcut file is shared among all users):

```
[Environment]::GetFolderPath("CommonDesktopDirectory")
```

Check out the full list of values for the [`SpecialFolder` Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder#fields).

Comment: Such a shame it doesn't have an Enum for the Download folder.

Answer (score 15):

If you need $Desktop\a.txt, use this

```
echo ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")+"\a.txt")
```

Answer (score 10):

What you are looking for is known as the `$home` variable. It's one of PowerShell's built-in [automatic variables](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-automatic-variables.html).

It defaults to the user-profile path, so drill down to the desktop like this:

```
If (Test-Path "$home\Desktop\Google Chrome.lnk") {
    Remove-Item "$home\Desktop\Google Chrome.lnk"
}
```

Comment: This works for a local desktop, but not for a redirected desktop like in my scenario.